Unexpected behavior with a couple of string in 16-bit assembly
I am trying to make a simple command line in 16-bit assembly using NASM and QEMU. And so far everything was working until I added one more string.
When I add another string the program doesn't display everything like it should.
When I add the last msgHelpEcho string it displays the prompt instead of ">" like this " >", or when I type help it displays the first few commands correct but the last one always is either cut in half, or missing, or turned in to an empty space " ".
I have searched reasons for this for the past few days and I found that moving around the declaration of the string to a different line in the code changes the output, but it is still not correct.
Thanks in advance! This is the code:
org 0x8000 ; the program starts from 8000
bits 16 ; the program is 16-bit

; si - for read and write strings
; di - for comparing commands

section .text

global _start

_start:
    call cls ; clear screen

; this is the start of the kernel
mov si, titleString ; print the title string
call printStr

mov si, newLine
call printStr

main:
    mov si, prompt ; this is the char befor the UI
    call printStr

    ; here the kernel asks for user input
    mov di, readBuffer
    call getInput

    ; here we split the input in to caommand and arguments
    mov si, readBuffer
    call splitCommand

    ; here are the commands
    mov si, readBuffer
    cmp byte [si], 0 ; to see if there is a blank line
    je main

    mov si, command
    mov di, cmdclear
    call cmpUI
    jc cls

    mov si, command ; this is the help command
    mov di, cmdHelp
    call cmpUI
    jc .help

    mov si, command ; this is for the echo command
    mov di, cmdEcho
    call cmpUI
    jc .echo

    mov si, command ; this is for the shutdown command
    mov di, cmdShutdown
    call cmpUI
    jc .shutdown

    mov si, badCmd ; if all command aren't triggered then print no such command
    call printStr
    jmp main

    .shutdown:
        ; turn off the system
        mov ax, 0x5307
        mov bx, 0x0001
        int 0x15
        jmp .shutdown

    .help:
        mov si, msgHelp ; help text
        call printStr

        ;mov si, msgHelpHelp ; -help
        ;call printStr

        ;mov si, msgHelpExit ; -shutdown
        ;call printStr

        ;mov si, msgHelpClear ; -clear
        ;call printStr

        jmp main

    .echo:
        mov si, arguments
        call printStr

        mov si, newLine
        call printStr

        jmp main

    jmp main ; infinite loop

printStr:
    mov ah, 0x0e ; Move 0x0e in ah to use interupts
    mov al, [si] ; Move the first char of the string in al
    psloop:
        int 0x10 ; 0x10 is interrupt for print
        inc si ; incrementing the si stack index
        mov al, [si] ; moving the new char from the string in the si stack to al
        cmp al, 0 ; comparing al to 0
        jne psloop ; is al is not 0 loop back
        ret
    ret

getInput:
    xor cl, cl

    .loop:
        mov ah, 0x00 ; this is for the interrupt
        int 0x16 ; this interrupt is for reading the next char

        cmp al, 0x08 ; if backspace is pressed
        je .backspace

        cmp al, 0x0d ; if enter is pressed
        je .done

        cmp cl, 0x3f ; if 63 chars are entered
        je .loop

        mov ah, 0x0e ; when something is entered print it
        int 0x10

        stosb ; put the char in the buffer
        inc cl
        jmp .loop

    .backspace:
        cmp cl, 0 ; if it is the beginning of the string
        je .loop

        dec di
        mov byte [di], 0 ; delete the char
        dec cl ; decrement counter as well

        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, 0x08
        int 0x10 ; backspace on the screen

        mov al, ' '
        int 0x10 ; blank char out

        mov al, 0x08
        int 0x10 ; backspace again

        jmp .loop

    .done:
        mov al, 0 ; null the terminal
        stosb

        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, 0x0d
        int 0x10
        mov al, 0x0a
        int 0x10 ; new line

        ret

cls:
    pusha ; push the stack
    mov al, 0x03 ; this is for the interrupt
    mov ah, 0x00 ; this is also for the interrupt
    int 0x10 ; this interrupt clears all the junk the BIOS prints
    popa ; pop the stack
    ret

cmpUI:
    .loop:
        mov al, [si] ; grab a byte from si
        mov bl, [di] ; grab a byte from di
        cmp al, bl
        jne .notequal

        cmp al, 0 ; are both bytes null
        je .done

        inc di
        inc si
        jmp .loop

    .notequal:
        clc ; not equal, clear the carry flag
        ret

    .done:
        stc ; equal, set the carry flag
        ret

splitCommand:
    mov cx, 0
    mov di, command

    .find_space:
        lodsb ; take a byte from si and put it in al
        cmp al, ' '
        je .found_space
        stosb ; take a byte from al and put it in di
        inc cx
        test al, al
        jnz .find_space
        jmp .done

    .found_space:
        mov di, arguments

    .copy_arguments:
        lodsb
        stosb
        test al, al
        jnz .copy_arguments

    .done:
        ret

section .data

; commands
cmdHelp db 'help', 0 ; this is for the help command
cmdShutdown db 'shutdown', 0 ; this is for shutting down the computer
cmdEcho db 'echo', 0 ; this is for the echo command
cmdclear db 'clear', 0 ; clear the screen

readBuffer times 64 db 0 ; the buffer for the read UI
prompt db '>', 0 ; this is the char before the read UI
titleString db 'Command line', 13, 10, 0 ; this is the string

; help texts
msgHelp db 'The available commands are:', 13, 10, 0 ; this is the message from the help command
msgHelpHelp db '-help     - displays all the commands', 13, 10, 0
msgHelpExit db '-shutdown - shuts down the computer', 13, 10, 0
msgHelpClear db '-clear    - clear the screen', 13, 10, 0
msgHelpEcho db '-echo     - echos the text after it', 13, 10, 0

newLine db ' ', 13, 10, 0 ; new line
badCmd db 'No such command.', 13, 10, 0 ; when there is no such command

section .bss

command resb 16 ; buffer to store command
arguments resb 64 ; buffer to store arguments

And here is the bootloader I use:
ORG 0x7C00
BITS 16

main:
    hlt

load_and_execute_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 1
    mov ch, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov bx, 0x8000
    mov cx, 0x0002
    int 0x13

    jmp 0x8000 ;jump to entry point of kernel...
    
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h


You did not show how you create the binary and how you load and run it. My guess is only part of your code ends up in memory because one of the steps is likely only processing a single sector.

Based on your observations I'd say it sounds like this code/data isn't entirely read into memory and has been cut off (it seems this file generates 578 bytes which is 2 512 byte sectors). Given the org is 0x8000 can I assume you have a bootloader that goes with this where you read this code/data into memory with something like int 13/ah=2? If that is the case are you sure you read enough sectors into memory? Maybe you read one sector and you need to read 2 sectors?

wait i'll edit the question and add the bootloader

As we said, you only load 1 sector.

To delimit code in a question, you should use three backticks \``.  You had apostrophes '''` which don't work.

I just made the bootloader load one more sector and now everything works correctly. Thank you everyone!

Changed the bootloader to load another sector and it works!
ORG 0x7C00
BITS 16

main:
    hlt

load_and_execute_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 2
    mov ch, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov bx, 0x8000
    mov cx, 0x0002
    int 0x13

    jmp 0x8000 ;jump to entry point of kernel...
    
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h

